# jsp:forward in jsp:include doesn't prevent the original page to finish processing?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

To understand the question I will explain the situation:
**main.jsp** - the main window of the application
**jsp_seacurity.jsp** - JSP file which send redirect in case user has no access to given page (I created separate file to reuse it in different pages)
**noaccess.jsp** - access denied page

In my main.jsp, one of the first lines is:

```
<jsp:include page="jsp_security.jsp?bo_item=main&bo_permission=view"/>
```

In jsp_security.jsp I do some checks and if the user doesn't have permission for specific part of application I have the following code:

```
<jsp:forward page="noaccess.jsp"/>
```

After signing in with user without permission for main.jsp, I have noticed, Glassfish was showing exception in log file, which was occurring in some line of main.jsp which is after my jsp:include. I have checked jsp:include documentation and that was what I found

> When the include action is finished, the JSP container continues
>   processing the remainder of the JSP file.

And now the question is, does it continue processing main.jsp even after I perform jsp:forward in jsp_security.jsp? Is there any workaround for this? I'm not pro in security, maybe what I'm doing is completely wrong?

Thanks for help,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. What this line puts in the generated servlet file (a jsp is compiled to a servlet), is `request.getRequestDispatcher("target.jsp").forward(req, resp)`.

This does not mean the `doGet()` method returns - it will continue to execute.

That's why you should use a `Filter` to add security checks. If the condition is not met, you don't call `chain.doFilter()` but redirect to a 'forbidden' page instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Filters sound to me perfect workaround, thanks for help going to read some docs about Filters ;)